# Get month from datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to search for all declarations in a certain month number. "declaration_date" is a datetime attribute. I have this, but it fails, any ideas?

```
declaration = Declarations.all(:conditions => ['declaration_date.strftime("%-m") = 2')
```

Comment: It's dependent on the SQL dialect. Please tag with your DBMS. Alternately, you could pull all records and filter in Ruby, but that is much slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want declarations within a month in a specific year?  If so, try something like this:

```
time_range = (DateTime.new(2001,2,3) - 1.month)..DateTime.new(2001,2,3)
declaration = Declaration.where( 'declaration_date' => time_range )
```

You can follow this technique to get declarations in the same month over several years.

See also, section 11.3 of the Active Record Query Interface docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

I expect the strftime to return a string, and you are comparing it with the integer 2.  Try comparing it with the string '2'.

```
declaration = Declarations.all(:conditions => ["'declaration_date.strftime("%-m") = '2'")
```